# IllegalArgumentException: transpose requires all collections have the same size

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have parquet files under different folders in ADLS and I want to merge them into one..
the folder structure to path is like this

I ran the code below to do this but getting an error saying
**"IllegalArgumentException: transpose requires all collections have the same size"**

```
files = dbutils.fs.ls('abfss://udl-container@container-name.dfs.core.windows.net/UserData/folder1/folder2/folder3/')

combined_df = None
for fi in files: 
    df = spark.read.parquet(fi.path)
    if combined_df == None:
       combined_df = df
    else:
      combined_df = combined_df.union(df)
```

anyone has can help resolve this error?

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hard to tell without any particular example. Do the data in the folders have all the same schema?

Answer (score 1):

There is a much easier, faster and more efficient way to read all the parquet files in a folder into spark dataframe than looping over a list of file paths returned by `dbutils.fs.ls()`.

```py
path = 'abfss://udl-container@container-name.dfs.core.windows.net/UserData/folder1/folder2/folder3/'

# use recursiveFileLookup if you have data in sub-folders
combined_df = spark.read.format("parquet")\
    .option("recursiveFileLookup", "true")\
    .load(path)
```

If you don't need recursion, but need all the files, just:

```py
combined_df = spark.read.format("parquet").load(path)
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-generic-options.html#recursive-file-lookup

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why... but if you use `.distinct()` after union, the code will work:

```
combined_df = combined_df.union(df).distinct()
```